# Store values of For loops to print in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I´m actually new in java. I have a textarea and I wanted to read line by line, which I could already solve. But what I want is that each one of those lines write it in an excel file. I have already managed to create an excel file and write to it. What the code below does is that it reads line by line and writes it in excel, but I don't know how many lines the textarea can have, so if in my code below I write more than 3 lines in the textarea, It will only write the first 3 in excel and if I write less than 3 it throws this error: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I want to write all the lines that I want in the textarea and that they are written in excel. Thanks

```
String[] lines = TextArea.getText().split("\\n");
    for(int i = 0 ; i< lines.length; i++){
        System.out.println( lines[i]);

    String [][] entry = new String [40][40];
    entrada [0] [0]= "A1";
    entrada [1] [0]= lines[0];
    entrada [2] [0]= lines[1];
    entrada [3] [0]= lines[2];

    String route="/Users/sushi/Documents/writexcel.xls";
    g.generateExcel(entry, route);
    }
```

Comment: "... but I don't know how many lines the textarea can have": After `TextArea.getText().split("\\n")`, you have `lines.length` though. Btw1.: There are other line feeds than `\n`. Should better be `.split("\r\n|\r|\n")`. Btw2.: Yes, arrays are fix in size after creating. To get around that, the [Collections Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) was introduced. Use [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead of an array.

Comment: You can use your for loop like this: `entrada [i + 1] [0]= lines[i];`